# Multiple Network Interface Cards on one computer

Tags: windows, networking

I am having mutliple Ethernet over USB devices which creates a new networks on my Windows PC. The default gateaway for all those devices is 192.168.8.1. There is no option in the device itself to change the IP. I am trying to plug in two USB's with one its IPv4 settings being set to 'automatic' and the other I gave a manual IPv4 settings (DG: 192.168.9.1). I can connect properly to the first USB which has its default IP. But when I try to connect to the second USB with manual settings, it wont let me and gives a time out error. I assume that the issue is that the devices need to run on 192.168.8.1 and simply wont work correctly if I just update the network settings in Windows itself. Is there a way around this so I am still able to use the two seperate USB's?

Comment: You didn't even bother to tell us what OS you're using!!!

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvience. I have edited my post.  @Chopper3

Comment: Why Windows 7? Maybe give us a bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve here, what sort of switches do you have, what's your DHCP server? More detail please

Comment: I've updated my question again @Chopper3.

Comment: I'm definitely not seeing any cohesive picture of what's going on here. It seems like you're maybe having an issue with resassigning your default gateway (so a routing problem) or a firewall zone issue, but I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish or if you need to route on any but one of these networks. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Edited the whole question @Spooler

Comment: You need "Source IP selection", see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2009/04/24/source-ip-address-selection-on-a-multi-homed-windows-computer/ but without more information on your OS it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If these devices all have the same address, connecting them simultaneously will be problematic. You're correct in that changing the settings in Windows won't be good enough - you need to be joined to the correct network in order to communicate with the USB devices (I assume hard-coded) address.

The most sound approach in this case would probably be to change the address of each device so they don't overlap once you put them into service.

In the absence of the "changing the device address" option, you may consider attaching each one via USB passthrough to a separate VM on your host in question and then forwarding that traffic over another virtual interface (could be host-only depending on your requirements) back to your host. This way you could NAT the problem away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will be able to get it working this way but I am still wondering if there is a bit more 'clean' way to do it as running alot of VM's will cost alot of resources from my computer.

Comment: If you use a tiny little Linux distro to pull it off, it can be pretty lightweight while still affording your the isolation required for that approach. For example, you can probably get away with less than half a gig of RAM for each VM. As far as a more clean way to do it, you could isolate your traffic based on NIC rather than just address alone, but I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. VMs are probably the most generic solution that will allow you to get to everything at once.

Comment: Is there a way that I can host a Linux VM with the specific USB passthrough and access the running website outside of the VM with the VM IP? Usually this isnt an issue as you run a Localhost webserver and just browse to the VM IP. But since the IP it will host it on is 192.168.8.1 I am still wondering if I can access it from outside a VM.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I imagine you'd want to do it. You can pull that off by putting each of these passed through NIC addresses through a NAT on the VM.

Comment: However, this is an extremely generic solution. There is probably a more graceful way to accomplish this that does not involve abusing VMs and NAT. You may want to investigate the link that @LucaGibelli posted above in your question as a potential different avenue that would use a single hosts network stack.